# Disable emails from Orchestration Flow Work Item

Tags: email, visual-workflow, process-automation

We have an Orchestration flow that we are assigning to a public group. Whenever an interactive step gets created it is sending an email to the entire group, however, we have different methods of determining who this work item should be assigned to so the email is not needed. How can we turn off the sending of this email?

[image: Error Email]

There is already a help item from about a year ago found on trailhead, [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000FYGLDSA5). I posted to see if a workaround or feature has been found/added since then.

Comment: Hey there! Just updating this as I found this link to a [Salesforce Architects roadmap](https://architect.salesforce.com/roadmaps/roadmap-explorer?product=Flow+Orchestration#:~:text=Disable%20Automatic%20Emails) saying they will add this feature in early 2024. Will update the answer once it's implemented!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating this with an answer as an update is coming out in Spring '24.

You can now disable emails by default from the Process Automation Settings in Setup. (As of 9th Jan 2024) This will only work on sandboxes but should soon be released into production environments.

[image: Screenshot of setting in Process Automation Settings]